# Cassandra "Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." during write

Tags: php, cassandra

I'm using Datastax PHP Cassandra Driver and Cassandra 2.2.5 on Windows 10. This is a single-node cluster, and the keyspace replication of

```
{
    'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
    'replication_factor': 1
}
```

This is the table I'm inserting to:

```
CREATE TABLE MyDocuments (
    "label" varchar,
    "fileName" varchar,
    "blob" blob,
    "createdTime" bigint,
    "lastUpdateTime" bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY("label", "fileName")
);
```

When I tried to insert a row with a blob that is 16419KB large, it gave me this error message `Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.`
The row is not inserted at all.

Inserting a row with a blob that is 16379KB worked fine.

The log files don't show anything. When the operation fails, nothing is appended to any log files inside Datastax / Cassandra folders.

After a few hours of Googling, I still have no clue as to why this is happening. I have tried increasing `write_request_timeout_in_ms` to `20000` in the settings (`cassandra.yaml`), but it does not help.

Does anyone know why a write seems to fail in this way when the size exceeds ~16MB?

**Update:**

I updated Cassandra to v3.7, same observation, but the error message now says `Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures`.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to increase `commitlog_segment_size_in_mb` to a higher value. Try `64MB` instead.

It increases the size of the commit record segment. This property determines the *maximum mutation size* (`max_mutation_size_in_kb`), defined as *half of the segment size*. By default is 32MB, which made your record were overflowing the maximum mutation size.

From the [docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html?hl=cassandra.yaml):

> (Default: 32MB) Sets the size of the individual commitlog file
>   segments. A commitlog segment may be archived, deleted, or recycled
>   after all its data has been flushed to SSTables. This amount of data
>   can potentially include commitlog segments from every table in the
>   system. The default size is usually suitable for most commitlog
>   archiving, but if you want a finer granularity, 8 or 16 MB is
>   reasonable.
>
> This property determines the maximum mutation size, defined as half
>   the segment size. If a mutation's size exceeds the maximum mutation
>   size, the mutation is rejected. Before increasing the commitlog
>   segment size of the commitlog segments, investigate why the mutations
>   are larger than expected. Look for underlying issues with access
>   patterns and data model, because increasing the commitlog segment size
>   is a limited fix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link to docs. Do you happen to know if there are any tradeoffs in increasing the commitlog segment size?

Comment: Yes, it can bring commit delays if increased further. You will want to keep that blob small tho @light